# Populate a Dropdown list by grouping using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list which is used for holding Email Templates . Now , I have categorized this into two types of Templates . One is 'User Generated Templates' and other 'System Generated Templates' .

I have the functionality to keep adding the Templates and they get populates into the Dropdown .

The important part here is to "Group" the Templates as 'Email' and 'System'. I have a condition that, Whenever "USER TEMPLATES" are added , they should be placed above the "system templates"

I need to do populate a Dropdown list such that it gets grouped according to the "User" and "System" templates with AngularJS . How do i do this ?

Seeking Help !

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see any question here. Please edit your post and write down what seems to be the problem.

Comment: @EelLee : I wish to populate dropdown such tht it gets grouped according to the types

Comment: Can you post any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following structure for the templates :

```
$scope.templates = [{
    type: 'Email',
    name: 'Template u1'
}, {
    type: 'Email',
    name: 'Template u2'
}, {
    type: 'System',
    name: 'Template s1'
}, {
    type: 'Email',
    name: 'Template u3'
}, {
    type: 'System',
    name: 'Template s2'
}, {
    type: 'System',
    name: 'Template s3'
}];
```

If you want to group them by type in the dropdown you will declare your `select` element like that :

```
<select ng-model="template" ng-options="template.name group by template.type for template in templates">
    <option value=''>Select a template</option>
</select>
```

**Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/4zad66jx/1/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer . .. Need one more help .. I am using <input file >for  file uploading multiple files .  I need to make client side validations for accepting only "txt/pdf/doc" files without using any plugin/library .