# Angularjs Select with group and initial value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a form that includes a SELECT element. I load the possible values in my controller from a function that returns the data from a database. I want to group the options by a group name.

I have the list of options loading properly showing the grouping. My problem, is the initial value is not displaying - this is based on a data model. It shows as blank. If I choose any option in the list, it does properly display.

I followed the example from this solution [Populate a Dropdown list by grouping using AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103427/populate-a-dropdown-list-by-grouping-using-angularjs)

From the various other examples that I have seen, this should work...I'm guessing it is some little thing I accidentally overlooked.

This loads the possible values for the drop down:

```
    $http.get("api/getIndustry").success(function(data){
        $rootScope.industryData = [];
        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
            $rootScope.industryData.push({
                group: data.group,
                id: data.id, 
                text:  data.text
            });
        });                      
    });
```

For now, I am trying to initially set a selected value (eventually it will be set from reading a record):

```
    $scope.example3model = {group: 'Energy and Natural Resources', id: '25', text: 'Utilities'};
```

And this is a portion of my view.

```
<td colspan="4" ng-hide="editableForm.$visible">
    <select ng-model="example3model" class="form-control input-md" ng-options="industry.text group by industry.group for industry in industryData" >
    </select></br>
    {{example3model}}    <- did this to see what was chosen
</td>
```

I'm not sure what else to try to get this to work...the only problem I see right now is that the list is not showing the 'default' value of what is initially in example3model (so the list shows as blank). If I choose a value in the list it is displayed correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the `$rootScope.industryData` array contain the exact object you're setting as initial for `$scope.example3model`? I would either set the initial value looping the data array and pointing to the object reference there

Comment: yes, as far as I can tell it is in there exactly. At first, I did notice the id field wasn't in the same format but fixed that. The screen shows the value when the screen displays just not in the drop down as being selected. I chose the exact same option from the list and it displayed exactly the same.

Comment: Please try this: `$scope.example3model = $rootScope.industryData.filter(function(data){ return +data.id === 25 })[0]` and tell me if it works, we need to use the same referenced object in the array for the initial value

Comment: that works!  hmmm...so I am guessing that means I am not setting the initial value properly, right?  and although they look similar something is not quite right.

Comment: they both print out to the console as this:
{group: "Energy and Natural Resources", id: "25", text: "Utilities"}
{group: "Energy and Natural Resources", id: "25", text: "Utilities"}
something is still making them not equal, but not sure what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set the initial value to an object literal, and even though it may look the same as one inside the select options it is not.

This happens because of how *Javascript* and *AngularJS* both work to set that initial object-value (note that this wouldn't happen if options was an array of primitives such as numbers and strings): `{}` and `{}` look the same from a human perspective, but they're clearly not the same in JS, try doing this in the browser console:

```
{} == {}
// this will be false
{ a: 1 } == { a: 1 }
// this will be false as well
```

Now, what Angular does behind the scenes is checking if the `ngModel` matches any *reference* inside `ngOptions`, that's why we need to set the initial value *specifically* referenced from the options array.

The initialization, in your example, must be something like this in the specific case you provided *(note that I'll be hard-coding the `id` to match the needs of your post, but you could change it to match whatever you need)*

```
const defaultId = 25;
$scope.example3model = $rootScope.industryData.find(data => +data.id === defaultId)
```

Now the `ngModel` value is pointing to the referenced array object that we want.

[* Take a look at the official documentation about complex models for ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#complex-models-objects-or-collections-)

*[note that this will not work if none of the objects in the `ngOptions` array has that defaulted id as it will not match any of them]*

Comment: Thank you so very much! I think I will be able to work with what you provided in order to do the lookup and assignment as you suggested. Quite frustrating - was driving me nuts :)